# How to write fields dynamically to a csv file using a tJava

Tags: talend

I'm using Talend to extract database field names from the table and write to a csv them after replacing the "_" in field names with " ". I want to have these values against the actual headers.

eg:

```
|First_Name|Last_Name|
|----------|---------|
|First Name|Last Name|
```

My job looks similar to following.
[image]

Code in tJavaRow is as follows:

```
    for (java.lang.reflect.Field field: 
 input_row.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
 String fieldName = field.getName();
 String newFieldName = null;
 newFieldName = fieldName.replaceAll("_", " ");
 context.columnName = newFieldName;
 System.out.println("Field name is " + context.columnName );
     }
```

How can I get the value of this context variable for each field in csv file? If I directly use it in the tmap it will only have name of the last field as value.
tmap I had between tJava and the tFileOutputDelimited.[image]

Comment: Is this just about exchanging dynamically headers? How does the `tMap` look like? What is stored in the context?

Comment: @tobi6 context has columnName

Answer (score 0):

you cannot change schema as they are treated as declared variables in java code which is generated in backend.
your schema "**|First_Name|Last_Name|**" is converted into as below:
String First_Name =null;
String Last_Name = null;
So you cannot change those schema column names on fly.

But you can create a record from the column names which you are retrieving from database by using the delimiter you want(**lets take comma**)

```
for (java.lang.reflect.Field field : input_row.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    String fieldName = field.getName();
    context.columnName = context.columnName + "," + fieldName.replaceAll("_", " ");
}
```

And now, before writing your data into a csv file, write this header record in **context.columnName** into that csv file.
After writing the header record, append your data to that file by checking "Append" check box in tFileOutputDelimitted.

Comment: I'm not too sure how I can write to a context.columnName to a csv directly from tJavaRow as the context.columnName value is dynamic.